# Create several subcategories without using the GUI in craft

Tags: craft3, categories

I have to create the following categories hierachically : One book has between 1 and 150 chapters.
I have to do this for several books.  Dealing with chapters is painful using the GUI. Is there any way to achieve this directly using json, queries ?

**Category "Book 1" is consisted of 100 chapters subcategory**

- Book 1 -> Chap 1
- Book 1 -> Chap 2
- ...
- Book 1 -> Chap 100

**Category "Book 1" is consisted of 10 chapters subcategory**

- Book 2 -> Chap 1
- Book 2 -> Chap 2
- ...
- Book 1 -> Chap 10

Answer (score 1):

If you have the JSON of the chapters or want to create it, you could import them using FeedMe Pro (required to import the Category element type). It'll import the categories and create child categories if they're not already created.